# how to concatenate output with three layers into one layer in keras Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I got one output with three layers using following method, next layer I wanted also to use  Conv2D(filters=3),but input is one channel. how to how to concatenate the above output with three layers into one layer?

```
   dh= 50
   di= 598
   c_utt_j=np.array([[1, 467, 86, 251, 449, 35, 219, 287, 442, 492, 429, 195, 486, 489, 156, 333, 457, 216, 439, 536, 270, 53, 338, 401, 1]])
   c_uttcut_j=len(c_utt_j[0])
   max_length=c_uttcut_j

input = layers.Input(shape=(max_length, ),dtype='int32',  name='input')
emb_j=layers.Embedding(di, dh,weights=[Wemb], input_length=max_length)(input)
wh1_j=layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3,50),strides=(1,50),padding='same',activation='tanh')(emb_j22)
```

by the way, I was doing text classification, the reason that I used Conv2D is just I think there are no difference between Conv2D and Conv1D when dealing with text.

Comment: Can you give more model code? We don't know parameters.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to feed concatenated tensor that you got from concatenating outputs from 3 different layers or do you want to concatenate outputs from 3 Cnv2D layers into one output?

Comment: my model is one embeding layer, then one Conv2D layer, then the second Conv2D layer. the first Conv2D layer is 1 in, 3 output which means 3 filters .The output shape is [25,1,3]. (25 is text length.).My problem is in the second Conv2D, I want to use also 1 in ,3 output , I hope the input shape is [25,3],but the first Conv2D output is 3 output. how to change from [25,1,3] to [25,3]?